# Monadic coding style?

Tags: scala, coding-style, monads

I find myself writing my programs more and more in the style like this:

```
myList
  .map(el => ...)
  .filter(_....)
  .map { el =>
    ...
    ...
  }
  .zipWithIndex
  .foreach(println)
```

Often my subroutine consists entirely of such block of code. I never planned to change my style of coding into this, it just happened naturally as I used Scala more and more.

Is it correct to say that such code is written in "monadic style"? I do have a vague understanding of what a monad is, and I am using Scala's collections here, and those seem to be monadic types. On the other hand I am not creating any monadic types myself, I am just using them. In other words, when I want to say merely that I program in `take_something.change_it.change_it.use_it` style, is it ok to refer to it as "monadic style"?

Comment: No, that's just using _pointfree style_ in Haskell-speak (composition of many functions omitting their intermediate values). If you write a lot of `for { ... }` comprehensions using `flatMap` capabilities, that would be a lot closer to monadic style.

Comment: @EarlGray - `(x map foo)` vs. `x.map(foo)` is usually what Scala coders call "point free".

Comment: @RexKerr I'm not really a Scala guy, so I said _in Haskell-speak_ :) Anyway, Scala-pointfree has nothing to do with monadic style too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that programming that way is a consequence of using monads, but I'd only describe it as fully programming in monadic style if you're really relying on monads to program completely free of side-effects, using things like [IO monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_monad#The_I.2FO_monad) and [State monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_monad#State_monads). You tend to end up with a whole bunch of *nested* (as opposed to chained) `map`s, `flatMap`s, and `filter`s. The Scala `for...yield` construct helps organize code that works with multiple nested monads. You may find the book [Functional Programming in Scala](http://manning.com/bjarnason/) interesting, for really delving into that style.

Your example is certainly monadic in the smaller sense of using chained transformations on one monadic type. That pattern is used in a lot of code that I wouldn't necessarily describe as "monadic", and is sometimes called [method cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading) or the [fluent pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Scala).